# NullPointerException if checkbox is not cheked

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am having a checkbox in html like this :

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="subscribe">Subscribe For Answers</input>
```

And in my servlet i get its value by doing something like this :

```
String checked=new String();
checked=request.getParameter("subscribe");

if(!checked.isEmpty()){
            if(checked.compareTo("subscribe")==0)
            {
                ps.setInt(4, 1);
            }
}
else  {
            ps.setInt(4,0);
}
```

But if checkbox is not checked then it gives Null Pointer Exception.Please help to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox is not checked, the request won't contain any `subscribe` parameter, so `checked` will be `null`. You want something like:

```
String checked = request.getParameter("subscribe");
if (checked != null && !checked.isEmpty()) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

As an aside, do you really want to not call `ps.setInt(4, ...)` at all if the parameter value *is* provided, but isn't "subscribe"? Currently, you've got three options:

- Not provided: set to 0
- Provided and equal to "subscribe": set to 1
- Otherwise: don't set

(It's also not clear why you're using `String.compare` rather than `String.equals`...)